# How to map Ctrl+Shift+<key> in Neovim + Tmux in Alacritty

Tags: tmux, neovim, alacritty

I use neovim with tmux in alacritty and I'm currently tring to create keymaps to the combinations `<C-S-h>` and `<C-S-l>` (`<S-h>` and `<S-l>` are already mapped), but I can't get it to work when running tmux.

I've already followed [this tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/mbj8m5/how_to_setup_ctrlshiftkey_mappings_in_neovim_and/), but it only works **outside** of tmux. Is there some extra tmux configuration that I need to do in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior as you and got it to work both inside and outside tmux by changing the '5u' in chars to '6u' (7u and up did not work).

Answer (score 0):

shift + char = Capital of that Char

```
lowercase
<C-h> -> <C-s>
<C-l> -> <C-l>

uppercase
<C-S-h> -> <C-H> 
<C-S-l> -> <C-L>
```